# Vectorizing scalars/vector division

Tags: matlab, vectorization

If for example I have:

```
Q1=4;
Q2=5;
PG=2:60

A1=Q1./sqrt(PG);
A2=Q2./sqrt(PG);

plot(PG,A1)
plot(PG,A2)
```

can I do sth like : ?

```
Q=[Q1,Q2];
A=Q./sqrt(PG);
plot(PG,A(1))
plot(PG,A(2))
```

or sth to avoid the A1 and A2?

Comment: Why not ``Q=[4;5];A=Q/sqrt(PG);plot(PG,A,'o');`` if ``PG`` is indeed a scalar?

Comment: This is a question about vectorizing an operation, not about plotting, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A=bsxfun(@rdivide,[Q1;Q2],sqrt(PG))` will do (note the semicolon, not comma, between `Q1` and `Q2`), but if the code in the question is your use case and you ever want anyone else to read and understand the code, I'd advise against using it.

You have to address the rows of `A` using `A(1,:)` and `A(2,:)` (no matter how you get to `A`), but you probably want to `plot(PG,A)` anyway.

[edit after first comment:]
`rdivide` is simply the name of the function usually denoted `./` in MATLAB code, applicable to arrays of the same size or a scalar and an array. `bsxfun` will simply apply a two-argument function to the other two arguments supplied to it in a way it considers best-fitting (to simplify a bit). `arrayfun` does something similar: applying a function to all elements of one array. To apply here, one would need a function having `PG` hard-coded inside.

Comment: Regarding your previous answer (with cell2mat) it worked fine!Now, with bsxfun I can't understand how to use it.

Comment: @George Do you mean it does not work for you, or that my first attempt `cellfun(arrayfun(@(x) x./(PG),[Q1;Q2],'UniformOutput', false))` is simply easier to understand?